# SSH connection between two computers behind nat

Tags: linux, ssh

I would like to ssh into my friends computer which is behind a NAT from my computer which is behind a different NAT(college wifi). Is there any way this can be achieved?

Comment: Are they behind _the same_ NAT?

Comment: No. They are behind different NATs

Comment: If the friend's PC is behind a router they or you have access to, simply forward an arbitrary port to the friend's PC the SSH server is running on (i.e. WAN port 56150 to LAN port 22 at IP _X_ [friend's PC's LAN IP]).  It would be ideal for DDNS to be setup on the Friend's router, however DDNS can be configured on the Friend's PC via software from Dyn (for example).  DDNS is required if the ISP is not providing a static WAN IP.

Comment: Its college wifi so cant forward port

Comment: If it is college wifi, it might also be that SSH connections are firewalled as well.

Comment: Possible solution: [SSH connection between two behind-nat computers through third public-ip computer](https://superuser.com/questions/315523/ssh-connection-between-two-behind-nat-computers-through-third-public-ip-computer)

Answer (score 2):

You need a public facing port to connect to. A good solution is NGROK , search "TCP tunnel". It exposes the port to its own temporary domain name that is public facing.

Here is a link to their documentation: https://ngrok.com/docs

Hope this helps, best regards